# Laravel - Auth::attempt

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Muy buenos días comunidad de Laravel, hoy vengo con un reto, espero sus favorables respuestas.

Quisiera poder autentificarme con usuarios de dos bases de datos distintas. Validar la información no es problema. En mi aplicación tengo las conexiones preparadas. ( config/database.php he configurado una conexión para 'db1' y 'db2' ) Realmente mi duda surge cuando personalizo el login, hago uso del código Auth::attempt, el cual usa la conexión por defecto incluso si intento previamente setear la conexión del modelo User:

```
$user = \App\User; 
$user->setConnection('mysql2');
if(Auth::attempt($credencials)){
   return Redirect::to('/home');
}
```

Esto me genera un error ya que intento validar datos de db2 (nombre de la conexion: mysql2). Auth::attempt está configurado para que use la conexion por defecto en este caso 'mysql' (base de datos db1).

En este caso quiero lograr hacer un login personalizado a este nivel. Agradezco sus respuestas.